# Should the example for search filter `answers` use a higher number?

Tags: feature-request

Should the example for search filter `answers` use a bigger number than one?

Search filters are documented in `/search`, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search for Stack Overflow. (These filters were originally described in a Stack Overflow blog entry: [Stack Overflow Search – Now 61% Less Crappy](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/stack-overflow-search-now-61-less-crappy/).)

The line for filter `answers` reads (description and example):

```
questions that have a minimum number of answers         answers:1 apples oranges
```

As the allowed value is not limited to just 0 or 1: should a number higher than 1 be used?

Comment: Is this intended to distinguish it from the other on/off options (e.g.  `intitle`). If so, this seems like a good idea to me.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Other uses are for on/off or yes/no switches so this would make it clear that it's the number of answers you're looking for.